# Default variable value passed to function breaks script in IE11 but doesn't seem required

Tags: javascript

```
var fbOptout = function(reload=0) {
  reload = (typeof reload !== 'undefined') ?  reload : 0;
  var optoutWindowDisableKey = 'fb-disable';
  document.cookie = optoutWindowDisableKey + '=true; expires=Thu, 31 Dec 2999 23:59:59 UTC; path=/';
  window[optoutWindowDisableKey] = true;
  if(reload){
    location.reload();
  }
};
```

This is failing in IE11 due to the default variable value **reload=0** passed along to the function.

Since the next line is

```
reload = (typeof reload !== 'undefined') ?  reload : 0;
```

this passing of the default value isn't even needed AFAIK or am I missing something?

Comment: this is an es6 feature therefore not supported by IE11

Comment: Correct, this should not be needed. The next line is the common “fallback” for default parameters not really existing before ES6.

Comment: Notice that "reload" will never be not declared, because it is a parameter, so there is no need for the `typeof` trick. You can make it shorter: `reload !== undefined`.

Comment: @E.Zacarias yeah, I figured but this is an external script I'm touching as little as possible ... just need to get rid of the IE11 error.

Answer (score 2):

[IE doesn't support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters#Browser_compatibility) default parameters.

Remove the `reload=0`:

```
var fbOptout = function(reload) {
```

You already have a check that assigns a default value to `reload` on the 2nd line, any way.